# Javascript Array processing

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have an array:

```
var names = ['John', 'Jim', 'Joe'];
```

and I want to create a new array from names which afterwards will look like:

```
newNames = ['John John', 'Jim Jim', 'Joe Joe']
```

What I came up with is the following:

```
var newNames = [];
var arr = null;
var loop = 0;

$.each(names, function (i, item) {
  arr = [];
  loop = 2;
  while (loop--) {
    arr.push(item);
  }
  newNames.push(arr.join(' '));
});
```

Seems like there should be a shorter, easier way to do this. As you can see we can repeat the names with a space n times. I'm experimenting with different ideas/concepts, having fun.

Comment: Since then, JavaScript has added `String.repeat()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a function that operates on values in the manner you want...

```
function dupe(n) { return n + " " + n }
```

---

then use `Array.prototype.map`...

```
var newNames = names.map(dupe)
```

---

or jQuery's not quite compliant version, `$.map`...

```
var newNames = $.map(names, dupe)
```

---

You can also create a function factory that will make a `dupe` function that will add the operate on the value a given number of times.

```
function dupeFactory(i) {
    return function(n) {
        var j = i-1
        ,   m = n
        while (j--)
            m += " " + n
        return m
    }
}
```

Then use it like this...

```
var newNames = names.map(dupeFactory(3))
```

---

Or make reuse of the functions created from the factory, by storing them in variables...

```
var dupe3 = dupeFactory(3),
    dupe6 = dupeFactory(6)

names.map(dupe6)
```

Comment: Dang, this seems to be pretty straightforward and very clean. Thanks much.

Comment: @DavidWhitten: You're welcome. I also added a solution that lets you choose how many times you want to append the name.

Comment: Your `dupeFactory` does not work, it creates 2^n repetitions...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6THSR/

Answer (score 7):

You could use the native `Array.map` method in modern browsers ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))

```js
const newNames = ['John', 'Jim', 'Joe'].map( name => `${name} ${name}`);
console.log(newNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to have a variable `loop` value:

```
var names = […];

var newNames = names.slice(0); // copy the names for the first part
for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++)
    for (var j=1; j<2; j++) // sic
        newNames[i] += " "+names[i];
```

Else, for a constantly two times a simple string concatenation will be shorter. Together with [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var newNames = names.map(function(name) {
    return name+" "+name;
});
```